# Java: JSON -> Protobuf & back conversion

Tags: java, json, serialization, persistence, protocol-buffers

I have an existing system, which is using *protobuf-based* communication protocol between GUI and server. Now I would like to add some persistence, but at the moment protobuf messages are straight converted to a third-party custom objects.

Is there a way to convert *proto* messages to *json*, which could be then persisted to database.

**N.B.:** I don't much like an idea of writing binary protobuf to database, because it can one day become not backward-compatible with newer versions and break the system that way.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "because it can one day become not backward-compatible with newer versions"? And what makes you think JSON would be more likely to stay backward-compatible? Are you talking about newer versions of your proto schema, or newer versions of protocol buffers in general? My experience is that storing protocol buffers is absolutely fine...

Comment: Note that Protocol Buffers 3 (currently in beta) will directly support JSON.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544580/is-there-a-standard-mapping-between-json-and-protocol-buffers

Answer (score 65):

As mentioned in [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38441368/159452), since [v3.1.0](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.1.0) this is a supported feature of ProtocolBuffers. For Java, include the extension module [com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/) and use [JsonFormat](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat.java) like so:

```
JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields().merge(json, yourObjectBuilder);
YourObject value = yourObjectBuilder.build();
```

Answer (score 53):

We are currently using [protobuf-java-format](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-java-format/) to convert our Protobuf messages (anything subclass of `Message`) into a JSON format to send over our web API.

Simply do:

```
  JsonFormat.printToString(protoMessage)
```

Comment: This is very helpful. It would also be helpful if you could share the API to convert a JSON dump to protocol buffer.

Comment: This library seems dead as it's in Google Code archives, non exported to GitHub, with important issues still open

Comment: @LouisCAD yes, but i think its now in https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat

Comment: The code is located here (as of version 3.4.0) [com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat.java](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat.java)

Comment: The project (providing support for old versions of protobuf) has moved here https://github.com/bivas/protobuf-java-format

Comment: This seems to have changed to `JsonFormat.printer().print(MessageOrBuilder)` in newer versions.

Comment: Looks like the most recent one is here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java-util
with docs at: https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java-util/latest/index.html

Comment: @vanguard69 To go backwards is a bit more cumbersome, but it's straightforward: MyMessage.Builder builder = MyMessage.newBuilder(); JsonFormat.parser().merge(jsonString, builder); MyMessage myMessage = builder.build();

Answer (score 40):

> I don't much like an idea of writing binary protobuf to database, because it can one day become not backward-compatible with newer versions and break the system that way.

Converting protobuf to JSON for storage and then back to protobuf on load is much *more* likely to create compatibility problems, because:

- If the process which performs the conversion is not built with the latest version of the protobuf schema, then converting will silently drop any fields that the process doesn't know about. This is true both of the storing and loading ends.
- Even with the most recent schema available, JSON <-> Protobuf conversion may be lossy in the presence of imprecise floating-point values and similar corner cases.
- Protobufs actually have (slightly) stronger backwards-compatibility guarantees than JSON. Like with JSON, if you add a new field, old clients will ignore it. Unlike with JSON, Protobufs allow declaring a default value, which can make it somewhat easier for new clients to deal with old data that is otherwise missing the field. This is only a slight advantage, but otherwise Protobuf and JSON have equivalent backwards-compatibility properties, therefore you are not gaining any backwards-compatibility advantages from storing in JSON.

With all that said, there are many libraries out there for converting protobufs to JSON, usually built on the Protobuf reflection interface (not to be confused with the Java reflection interface; Protobuf reflection is offered by the `com.google.protobuf.Message` interface).

Comment: How about storing the `return` value from `SerializeToString()` to a TEXT database column?

Comment: SerializeToString(), despite its name, does not produce text, it produces binary encoded data. So you need to store it to a database column that is typed correctly for arbitrary bytes.

Comment: @KentonVarda, what would be your suggestion for BI-friendly query-able DB storage format where the initial payload is acquired as protobuf message ? The simple approach seems to be protobuf message->Json->MongoDB. Is there more sophisticated path, maybe with flatbuffers  ? Thanks

Answer (score 21):

Adding to [Ophir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159452/ophir-radnitz)s answer, JsonFormat is available even before protobuf 3.0. However, the way to do it differs a little bit.

In Protobuf 3.0+, the JsonFormat class is a singleton and therefore do something like the below

```
String jsonString = "";
JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields().merge(jsonString,yourObjectBuilder);
```

In Protobuf 2.5+, the below should work

```
String jsonString = "";
JsonFormat jsonFormat = new JsonFormat();
jsonString = jsonFormat.printToString(yourProtobufMessage);
```

Here is a link to a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@moijes12/converting-protocol-buffers-data-to-json-and-back-with-gson-type-adapters-22d9f355673) I wrote that uses the JsonFormat class in a TypeAdapter that can be registered to a GsonBuilder object. You can then use Gson's toJson and fromJson methods to convert the proto data to Java and back.

Replying to [jean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4131823/jean) . If we have the protobuf data in a file and want to parse it into a protobuf message object, use the merge method [TextFormat](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/TextFormat#merge-java.lang.CharSequence-com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry-com.google.protobuf.Message.Builder-) class. See the below snippet:

```
// Let your proto text data be in a file MessageDataAsProto.prototxt
// Read it into string  
String protoDataAsString = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("MessageDataAsProto.prototxt"));

// Create an object of the message builder
MyMessage.Builder myMsgBuilder = MyMessage.newBuilder();

// Use text format to parse the data into the message builder
TextFormat.merge(protoDataAsString, ExtensionRegistry.getEmptyRegistry(), myMsgBuilder);

// Build the message and return
return myMsgBuilder.build();
```

Comment: And this one for PROTO to JSON in 3.0+: `JsonFormat.printer().print(MessageOrBuilder)`

Answer (score 21):

## Generics Solution

Here's a generic version of Json converter

```
package com.github.platform.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.Builder;
import com.google.protobuf.Message;
import com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder;
import com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;

/**
 * Generic ProtoJsonUtil to be used to serialize and deserialize Proto to json
 * 
 * @author Marcello.deeSales@gmail.com
 *
 */
public final class ProtoJsonUtil {

  /**
   * Makes a Json from a given message or builder
   * 
   * @param messageOrBuilder is the instance
   * @return The string representation
   * @throws IOException if any error occurs
   */
  public static String toJson(MessageOrBuilder messageOrBuilder) throws IOException {
    return JsonFormat.printer().print(messageOrBuilder);
  }

  /**
   * Makes a new instance of message based on the json and the class
   * @param <T> is the class type
   * @param json is the json instance
   * @param clazz is the class instance
   * @return An instance of T based on the json values
   * @throws IOException if any error occurs
   */
  @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
  public static <T extends Message> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642021/calling-parsefrom-method-for-generic-protobuffer-class-in-java/33701202#33701202
    Builder builder = null;
    try {
      // Since we are dealing with a Message type, we can call newBuilder()
      builder = (Builder) clazz.getMethod("newBuilder").invoke(null);

    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException
        | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
      return null;
    }

    // The instance is placed into the builder values
    JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields().merge(json, builder);

    // the instance will be from the build
    return (T) builder.build();
  }
}
```

Using it is as simple as follows:

## Message instance

```
GetAllGreetings.Builder allGreetingsBuilder = GetAllGreetings.newBuilder();

allGreetingsBuilder.addGreeting(makeNewGreeting("Marcello", "Hi %s, how are you", Language.EN))
        .addGreeting(makeNewGreeting("John", "Today is hot, %s, get some ice", Language.ES))
        .addGreeting(makeNewGreeting("Mary", "%s, summer is here! Let's go surfing!", Language.PT));

GetAllGreetings allGreetings = allGreetingsBuilder.build();
```

## To Json Generic

```
String json = ProtoJsonUtil.toJson(allGreetingsLoaded);
log.info("Json format: " + json);
```

## From Json Generic

```
GetAllGreetings parsed = ProtoJsonUtil.fromJson(json, GetAllGreetings.class);
log.info("The Proto deserialized from Json " + parsed);
```

Comment: allGreetingsLoaded - what this object stands for ?

Comment: @ArthTilva that's just a reference of the Generics class GetAllGreetings.class.

Comment: This is exactly (more or less) the approach I've done in the past.

Answer (score 8):

Try `JsonFormat.printer().print(MessageOrBuilder)`, it looks good for proto3. Yet, it is unclear how to convert the actual `protobuf` message (which is provided as the java package of my choice defined in the .proto file)  to a com.google.protbuf.Message object.

Comment: Is this supposed to answer the question? It rather sounds a like question to the readers?

Answer (score 7):

Here is my utility class, you may use:

```java
package <removed>;
import com.google.protobuf.Message;
import com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder;
import com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;
/**
 * Author @espresso stackoverflow.
 * Sample use:
 *      Model.Person reqProto = ProtoUtil.toProto(reqJson, Model.Person.getDefaultInstance());
        Model.Person resProto = personSvc.update(reqProto); // service layer call
        final String resJson = ProtoUtil.toJson(resProto);
 **/
public class ProtoUtil {
    public static <T extends Message> String toJson(T obj){
        try{
            return JsonFormat.printer().print(obj);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Error converting Proto to json", e);
        }
    }
   public static <T extends MessageOrBuilder> T toProto(String protoJsonStr, T message){
        try{
            Message.Builder builder = message.getDefaultInstanceForType().toBuilder();
            JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields().merge(protoJsonStr,builder);
            T out = (T) builder.build();
            return out;
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(("Error converting Json to proto", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For protobuf 2.5, use the dependency:

```
"com.googlecode.protobuf-java-format" % "protobuf-java-format" % "1.2"
```

Then use the code:

```
com.googlecode.protobuf.format.JsonFormat.merge(json, builder)
com.googlecode.protobuf.format.JsonFormat.printToString(proto)
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, there is no shortcut to do it as per my findings, but somehow you
an achieve it in few simple steps

First you have to declare a bean of type 'ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter'

```
@Bean  
@Primary  
public ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {  
  return new ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter(JsonFormat.parser(), JsonFormat.printer());  
}
```

Then you can just write an Utility class like ResponseBuilder, because   it can parse the request by default but without these changes it can not   produce Json response. and then you can write few methods to convert the response types to its   related object type.

```
public static <T> T build(Message message, Class<T> type) {
  Printer printer = JsonFormat.printer();
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  try {
    return gson.fromJson(printer.print(message), type);
  } catch (JsonSyntaxException | InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
    throw new ApiException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Response   conversion Error", e);
  }
}
```

Then you can call this method from your controller class as last line like   -

```
return ResponseBuilder.build(<returned_service_object>, <Type>);
```

Hope this will help you to implement protobuf in json format.

Comment: is there a working example github project using like code above?

Comment: Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Parser and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: pn.api.protobuf.Proto$SearchResponse["unknownFields"]->com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet["parserForType"])

Answer (score 3):

Latest answer with google protobuf 3.7.0 :

Maven changes -- Add this to your pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.1</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <additionalProtoPathElements>
                <additionalProtoPathElement>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</additionalProtoPathElement>
            </additionalProtoPathElements>
            <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.7.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

This is the java class :

```
public class ProtobufTrial {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String jsonString = "";
    MyProto.MyEventMsg.Builder builder = MyProto.MyEventMsg.newBuilder();
    JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields().merge(jsonString, builder);
    MyProto.MyEventMsg value = builder.build();

    // This is for printing the proto in string format
    System.out.println(JsonFormat.printer().print(value));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a simple library ([here](https://github.com/safeuq/jackson-protobuf-java/tree/main)) to convert protoc generated Java objects to any Jackson supported dataformat (like JSON, YAML or anything... you name it). This allowed me to use all the Jackson supported serialization features on the converted output. It is based on Google's [protobuf-java-util](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/main/java) library.

Add the dependency and use the library as follows:

```java
MyMessage myMessage = MyMessage.newBuilder().build();
JsonMapper jsonMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
    .addModule(JavaProtoModule.builder().build()).build();
String serialized = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(myMessage);
```

Comment: I couldn't find the JsonMapper class in the lib. @Mohamed Safeuq J

Comment: @rupesh `JsonMapper` class is part of the [jackson-databind](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind) library. Make sure to include that in dependency as well.