# How to use google.protobuf.struct in proto file to store json result in gRPC java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-java

I Want to Return a JSON response from server to client in gRPC.

one possible way is to convert it to string return the response then convert back to Json Object in client side, but i want to know can we do better?.

i am doing some google and found we can do it with the help of **google.protobuf.struct**
but didn't actually find any good example.

i want an example how i can use it as JSON in java.

Comment: JSON is a string.  Your original solution is how to get a JSON result.  (If you want to do it more efficiently, then using an _actual_ protobuf instead of JSON might help.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using proto3, one option is to define a protobuf message that mirrors the JSON object you wish to populate. Then you can use [`JsonFormat`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat) to convert between protobuf and JSON.

Using a `com.google.protobuf.Struct` instead of a self-defined message can also work. There is an example shown in the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58198700/11500161).