# Is there a way to convert JSON to Protobuf in NIFI?

Tags: json, mqtt, apache-nifi, protobuf-java

Im attempting to implement an MQTT dataflow which requires the final delivery to be sent using sparkplug specifications.

However, i am unable to find a way to convert the contents of the flowfile to be in a protobuf format

Is there a way to do this conversion?

Comment: Hope you have proto definition? Or maybe generated or compiled java code for this proto? I think you could use executegroovyscript. But need more details to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options :

- The "dirty way" by using the [ExecuteScript processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) (using your preferred language groovy for e.g) and implementing something equivalent to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406211/how-to-convert-from-json-to-protobuf?rq=1)
- The cleanest way which is implement your own custom processor, you can start by using this one https://github.com/whiver/nifi-protobuf-processor and see if that fits your need.