# How to convert Json representation of protobuf back to protobuf?

Tags: json, protocol-buffers

I am sending a json string that represents a protobuf and I want to convert it back to the protobuf message that I desire.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: JSON -> Protobuf & back conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545401/java-json-protobuf-back-conversion)

Answer (score 1):

Posting this to complete @Srik's answer.

You can use the [JsonFormat](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat.java) class provided by Protobuf. Simply create a JsonParser object and parse the json string into a builder for the protobuf message. Below is a small snippet

```
private MyProtobufMessage parseJson(String jsonString) {
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    MyProtobufMessage.Builder messageBuilder = MyProtobufMessage.newBuilder();

   JsonFormat.parser().usingTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry.getEmptyTypeRegistry()).merge(jsonString, messageBuilder);
    return message.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it right after i posted the question! You can use Gson to convert to and from json to protobuf.