# How Protobuf encodes oneof message construct

Tags: python, serialization, protocol-buffers

For this python program running protobuf encoding when encoded gives following output:

> 0a 10 08 7f **8a 01** 04 08  02 10 03 **92 01** 04 08 02 10 03 18 01

What I don't understand is why there is a 01 after 8a, and again why 01 after 92. 
Seems for information element of type oneof, extra 01 is added, but why? 
Please help me, if any body understands protobuf encoding

```
import sys
import test2_pb2

def write_to_file(file,value):
    with open(file, "wb") as f:
        f.write(value)

def cell_test_dct():

  msg=test2_pb2.TestPrimM();
  msg.textx=1
  msg.testmsg.testint=127
  msg.testmsg.prbbundlingtype.x =2
  msg.testmsg.prbbundlingtype.static=
   test2_pb2.BUNDLE_SIZE_N_4_WIDEBAND
  msg.testmsg.bundlingtype.x =2
  msg.testmsg.bundlingtype.static=
  test2_pb2.BUNDLE_SIZE_N_4_WIDEBAND
  print (msg)
  str = msg.SerializeToString()
  #write_to_file("/tmp/protobuf_test_file.bin",str)

def main_test():
    cell_test_dct()

main_test()
```

For the following protobuf file :

```
package NR_TEST;

enum BundleSizeE {
    BUNDLE_SIZE_N_4 = 0;
    BUNDLE_SIZE_WIDEBAND = 1;
    BUNDLE_SIZE_N_2_WIDEBAND = 2;
    BUNDLE_SIZE_N_4_WIDEBAND = 3;
}

message DynamicBundleSizesM {
    // bundleSizeSet1
    optional BundleSizeE bundleSizeSet1 = 1;
    // bundleSizeSet2
    optional BundleSizeE bundleSizeSet2 = 2;
}

message PrbBundlingTypeM {
    optional uint32 x=1;
    oneof BundlingTypeC {
    BundleSizeE static = 2;
    DynamicBundleSizesM dynamic = 3;
    }
}

message Test {
    required int32 testint   =1;
    required PrbBundlingTypeM prbbundlingtype = 17;
    required PrbBundlingTypeM bundlingtype = 18;
}
message TestPrimM
{
  oneof TestMsgC {
    Test testmsg=1;
    int32  nomsg=2;
    }
    required  int32 textx=3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given [protobuf encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) your message is as follows:

```
0a .. varint key '1|010' -> field 1, type LENGTH_DELIMITED
    10 .. varint length -> 16
    Contents:
        08 .. varint key '1|000' -> field 1, type VARINT
            7f .. varint value -> 127
        8a 01 .. varint key '00000010001|010' -> field 17, type LENGTH_DELIMITED
            04 .. varint length -> 4
            Contents:
                08 .. varint key '1|000' -> field 1, type VARINT
                    02 .. varint value -> 2
                10 .. varint key '10|000' -> field 2, type VARINT
                    03 .. varint value -> 3
        92 01 .. varint key '00000010010|010' -> field 18, type LENGTH_DELIMITED
            04 .. varint length -> 4
            Contents:
                08 .. varint key '1|000' -> field 1, type VARINT
                    02 .. varint value -> 2
                10 .. varint key '10|000' -> field 2, type VARINT
                    03 .. varint value -> 3
18 .. varint key '11|000' field 3, type VARINT
    01 .. varint value -> 1
```

Integer value for tag of length-delimited field 17 is in binary: `10001|010` (`10001` is 17 and `010` is length-delimited [wire type](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#structure)) -> giving `10001010` (binary).

To encode this number as varint you need to adjust total bit length to a multiple of 7 (fill with zeroes):

> -> **000000**10001010

Then split it into groups of 7 bits:

> -> 0000001 0001010

Then reverse the order of those groups:

> -> 0001010 0000001

And add an extra bit to each group ([MSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Most_significant_bit)) -- zero to the last group and one to all other groups (MSB equal to 1 tells parser that there is another group following):

> -> **1**0001010 **0**0000001

Which gives `0x8A 0x01` in hexadecimal (your value).

Varint encoding is decribed [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints).

---

As far as I know the oneof construct does not change the wire format (it only extends parser logic that it ignores all, but the last field from a single oneof group).

Good luck!