# How to parse a byte array to a GeneratedMessage using Descriptor (protobuf, java)?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Given a [FieldDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.FieldDescriptor) and a `byte[]`, how do I parse the latter to my implementation of [GeneratedMessage](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage)?
Neither I can see any references to the corresponding java class (which contains generated `parseFrom(byte[] data)`) nor any methods returning something like `Parser<? extends GeneratedMessage>`.

In other words, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the same ([Generic Parsing of PB in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035027/generic-parsing-of-pb-in-java)) for a field (not for the whole message).

Comment: Do you mean [GeneratedMessage.getParserForType()](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage#getParserForType())?

Comment: @vlp, no. I only have an instance of `FieldDescriptor`